# Change pointer in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

How I can change my pointer (item that appears after the click) in Sublime Text? I use Sublime Text 4. For example, I want to change color of pointer and size of pointer.

[image: Example of caret]

I saw in doc of theme and color theme, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The item you're referring to is a [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)#Text_cursor). The `caret` color is controlled by the [caret global color](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#caret) in your color scheme and the `caret` settings in the global preferences.

To modify the color, you would:

1. Select `UI: Customize Color Scheme` from the command palette
2. In the right hand tab of the window that opens, add the `caret` key to the `globals` section and specify the color (such as the example below).
3. Save the file; as soon as you save the file, the change will take effect.

For example, you might make the file look like this (assuming you have no other color scheme customizations):

```json
// Documentation at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html
{
    "variables":
    {
    },
    "globals":
    {
        "caret": "magenta",
    },
    "rules":
    [

    ]
}
```

Which would make the caret magenta colored. See the [color scheme documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#colors) to see the various ways you can specify colors.

The preferences that control the caret size and shape are the following (taken directly from the default preferences file), shown with their default values. Use `Preferences > Settings` and add the settings you want to modify to the right hand pane as will other settings (you can also make them syntax specific).

```json
    // Valid values are "smooth", "phase", "blink" and "solid". Previous
    // versions of Sublime Text used "smooth" by default.
    "caret_style": "solid",

    // These settings control the size of the caret
    "caret_extra_top": 4,
    "caret_extra_bottom": 4,
    "caret_extra_width": 1,

    // When enabled, the caret will be drawn as a rectangle, using the width
    // of the current character
    "block_caret": false,
```